# Как закрасить пиксель с помощью WriteableBitmap?

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, графика, drawbitmap

Мне необходимо, имея координаты начала и конца отрезка, нарисовать его.

Координаты точек, составляющих отрезок, заданы массивами `x[n]` и `y[n]`.

Работа с координатами:

```
private void StartFirstLab_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(59, 166, 190));
    const int n = 50;
    const int xStart = 10;
    const int yStart = 10;
    const int xEnd = 40;
    const int yEnd = 40;

    var x = new int[n];
    var y = new int[n];

    x[0] = xStart;
    y[0] = yStart;

    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        x[i] = x[i - 1] + (xEnd - xStart) / n;
        y[i] = y[i - 1] + (yEnd - yStart) / n;
    }
}
```

Как нарисовать отрезок, закрасив соответствующие этим координатам пиксели?

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void CreatePicure()
    {
        var n = Convert.ToInt32(InputNcount.Text);
        var xStart = Convert.ToInt32(InputXstart.Text);
        var yStart = Convert.ToInt32(InputYstart.Text);
        var xEnd = Convert.ToInt32(InputXend.Text);
        var yEnd = Convert.ToInt32(InputYend.Text);

        var wb = new WriteableBitmap((int) Img.Width, (int) Img.Height, 200, 200, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);
        const int stride = 200;
        const int alpha = 255;

        var x = new int[n];
        var y = new int[n];

        x[0] = xStart;
        y[0] = yStart;

        for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            x[i] = x[i - 1] + (xEnd - xStart) / n;
            y[i] = y[i - 1] + (yEnd - yStart) / n;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            const int red = 155;
            const int blue = 100;
            const int green = 100;
            byte[] colorData = {blue, green, red, alpha};
            var rect = new Int32Rect(x[i], y[i], 1, 1);
            wb.WritePixels(rect, colorData, stride, 0);
        }
        Img.Source = wb;
    }
```